# Django retrieving users from tuples

Tags: django

```
 AUTH_USER_MODEL = getattr(settings, 'AUTH_USER_MODEL', 'auth.User')

 class Friend(models.Model):
     """ Model to represent Friendships """
     to_user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='friends')
     from_user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='_unused_friend_relation')
     created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

     objects = FriendshipManager()

     class Meta:
         verbose_name = _('Friend')
         verbose_name_plural = _('Friends')
         unique_together = ('from_user', 'to_user')

     def __unicode__(self):
         return "User #%d is friends with #%d" % (self.to_user_id, self.from_user_id)



 class FriendshipManager(models.Manager):

     def unread_requests(self, user):
         """ Return a list of unread friendship requests """
         key = cache_key('unread_requests', user.pk)
         unread_requests = cache.get(key)

         if unread_requests is None:
             qs = FriendshipRequest.objects.select_related(depth=1).filter(
                 to_user=user,
            viewed__isnull=True).all()
             unread_requests = list(qs)
             cache.set(key, unread_requests)

         return unread_requests

 class Person(models.Model):

     user = models.ForeignKey(User))
     name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', blank=True)


     def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

I am using this friendship model  . This model allow you to create friends between users.
I also have a UserProfile model called Profile which is above .

The below command shows how to view all the friendship request for a particular user

```
 >>> user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
 >>> user1 = User.objects.get(pk=1)
 >>> user2 = User.objects.get(pk=2)
 >>> user3 = User.objects.get(pk=3)
 >>> Friend.objects.add_friend(user1,user3)
 <FriendshipRequest: User #1 friendship requested #3>
 >>> Friend.objects.add_friend(user2,user3)
 <FriendshipRequest: User #2 friendship requested #3>
 >>> requests = Friend.objects.unread_requests(user=user3)
 >>> requests
 [<FriendshipRequest: User #1 friendship requested #3>, <FriendshipRequest: User
 #2 friendship requested #3>]
 >>> requests[0].to_user
 <User: hello>
```

I'm trying to show all the friendship request for a particular user with the images But

I can't do at the moment that because the requests are in tuples ( below is an example) .

I want to able to retrieve all the users who requested a friendship for a particular user

and then use those users to retrieve their users UserProfile model referring to Person so I can show their images in a template

in it's simplest form

How can I retrieve all the users who request a friendship ( below example is I can view the user name of one

```
     >>> requests = Friend.objects.unread_requests(user=user3)
     >>> requests
     [<FriendshipRequest: User #1 friendship requested #3>, <FriendshipRequest: User
     #2 friendship requested #3>]
      >>> requests[0].to_user
```

and then collect their UserProfile ( Person )

```
   Person.objects.filter ( ? )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of Friends

```
list_of_friend_requests = [r.to_user for r in requests]
```

Filter using [django's filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter)

```
persons = Person.objects.filter(user__in=list_of_friend_requests)
```